Binance API Websocket data stream (testnet)
Пишу на WINAPI.
Не могу получить данные через websocket. До этого работало, но произошли изменения.
Сначала подключаюсь к tesnet.binancefuture.com/ws-fapi/v1 получаю listenkey.
Далее подключаюсь к stream.binance.com и ничего не происходит.
До этого отправлял сейчас указывает ошибку.
{
"method": "REQUEST",
"params":
[
"<listenKey>@account", // request name 1
"<listenKey>@balance" // request name 2, if existing
],
"id": 12 // request ID.
}

и работало.

А у меня нормально рабоает. Анонимно и не в тестнете. https://codepen.io/rainner/pen/bjJYjp

Проверьте url-адрес. Скорее всего проблема в том что вы подключаетесь к stream.binance.com, а не к wss://stream.binancefuture.com/ws.

Я сделал ошибку в вопросе.... Да я подключаюсь именно к stream.binancefuture.com. Нужно ли отправлять какие-то данные при запросе  stream.binancefuture.com? В новых мануалах об этом ничего не указанно.

Каждый раз, когда вы создаете listenKey, он действителен в течение 60 минут с момента создания, и если вы не будете его использовать, он может истечь. Вы уверены что он у вас не истёк? Я бы вам порекомендовал отправлять KeepAlive запросы, чтобы поддерживать listenKey активным.

userDataStream.ping отправлял не помогает, listenkey не меняется. При подключении к stream.binancefuture.com/ws/ какие-то запросы отправлять как это было раньше? Если ничего не отправить тогда соединение прерывается.

Вы упомянули, что возникает ошибка. Можете ли вы предоставить контекст этой ошибки? Иначе можно долго гадать.

Нужно было вот так {"method":"SUBSCRIBE","params":["outboundAccountPosition"],"id":1 } В любом случае спасибо за желание помочь.
